# D3.js issue using the line chart defined function

Tags: d3.js

I'm using the defined function in d3.line() to draw two lines - one dotted, one flat.

```
var my_line = d3.line()
                .x(function(d){return x_scale(d.x_var)})
                .y(function(d){return y_scale(d.y_var)})
                .defined(function(d) {return d.defined; })


var my_dotted_line = d3.line()
                       .x(function(d){return x_scale(d.x_var)})
                       .y(function(d){return y_scale(d.y_var)})
                       .defined(function(d){return d.dot_defined;})
```

I only ever want to draw the dotted line between 2 consecutive points.

I've ended up creating 2 variables in the data:

1. defined - only false on the start row (see top dot below)
2. dot_defined - true on the start row and the consecutive row (top and bottom dot below)

This works perfectly for the dotted line but for the standard line it misses out 2 rows, even though only one entry == false.

[image: visual]

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add an image of how it should look like?

Comment: I have.  Image is above.

Comment: Okay, then let me rephrase: Could you add an image of how it looks like now?

Comment: That is how it looks like now...  I want the line on the left to run all the way to the dot.  I.e only leaving a gap in the line after the one 'false' row.

Comment: Hope that makes more sense?

Comment: Maybe I need to create a blind row in between the 2 dots?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

Solution is to add two data points where the top dot is.    One where defined == true and the next where defined == false.